# Error in running "sudo rosdep init"

Tags: ros, begginer-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had previously installed ROS Jade distribution, I have uninstalled it and trying to install Indigo, while running `sudo rosdep init` I get following error :

```
ERROR: default sources list file already exists:
    /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Please delete if you wish to re-initialize
```

As suggested in one of the answers I tried using `sudo pip uninstall rosdep` to uninstall previous version which gives `sudo: pip: command not found`

Is there any way to manually remove rosdep?
running `which rosdep` gives me this `/usr/bin/rosdep`

I found this question on the same error

> http://answers.ros.org/question/42818/tutorial-building-a-ros-package-rosdep-experienced-an-internal-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-copy/
>
> Blockquote

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235027/error-in-running-%22sudo-rosdep-init%22/) by [siddhesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26663/siddhesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-05-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-05-23**:
Did you try doing what it says? Deleting the file `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list` and then running `sudo rosdep init` again?

**Comment by [abhay2302](https://answers.ros.org/users/28289/abhay2302/) on 2016-10-21**:
it works for me. thanks

**Comment by [rishityagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/35103/rishityagi/) on 2018-05-13**:
hello there i am new to ROS and i facing the same problem
***etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list***
i cannot the file location to delete it.
Can you please help??

**Comment by [Thanhdeptrai](https://answers.ros.org/users/63896/thanhdeptrai/) on 2020-11-22**:
sudo rm /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to uninstall `rosdep`, just make sure it's up to date.

`rosdep` isn't too tied to ROS releases, so it should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [siddhesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26663/siddhesh/) on 2016-05-24**:
Thanks, it worked.